# Function prints correct result, returns wrong value

Tags: python-3.x, return-value

I know there are millions of similar questions, but I couldn't solve my case. I have a data set consisting of 4 columns (energy versus imaginary part of dielectric function in 3 polarizations). I want to apply [Kramers-Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations#Physical_interpretation_and_alternate_form) to find the real part for every energy point, so the result will be in the same dimensions as input data. For the sake of mwe, the data file looks like this:

```
 1.92000     0.45314     0.45774     0.44148
 1.92100     0.45387     0.45846     0.44223
 1.92200     0.45460     0.45918     0.44297
 1.92300     0.45533     0.45990     0.44372
 1.92400     0.45605     0.46062     0.44446
 1.92500     0.45677     0.46134     0.44520
```

So far my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math

data = np.loadtxt('opt.mgsin2gan', skiprows=1)
dw = data[1,0] - data[0,0]

## This is the expression being integrated.
def frac(x,pol):                
    arg = len(data)
    mid = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i,0] == x:
            pass
        else:
            mid += data[i,0]*data[i,pol]/(data[i,0]**2-x**2)
#            return 1+(2/math.pi)*mid*dw
            result = 1+(2/math.pi)*mid*dw
    print(result)

## Evaluates the expression for every energy point
def grid(a):
    for i in data[:,0]:
        frac(i,a)
#    return frac(i,a)

## Evaluates the expression for each polarization
def polarization():
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        grid(i)
#    return grid(i)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    polarization()
```

It prints the result on the screen, but I can't save the data in a text file since it doesn't return anything. However, when I uncomment return lines in each function, I get the wrong result. How can I save the result in a numpy array? Also, how can I make this code more elegant? Making it simpler probably will make it run in shorter time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are looking for something like this:

```
def frac(x,pol):                
    arg = len(data)
    mid = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i,0] == x:
            pass
        else:
            mid += data[i,0]*data[i,pol]/(data[i,0]**2-x**2)
#            return 1+(2/math.pi)*mid*dw
            result = 1+(2/math.pi)*mid*dw
    print(result)
    return result

## Evaluates the expression for every energy point
def grid(a):
    # return list here
    return [frac(i, a) for i in data[:,0]]

## Evaluates the expression for each polarization
def polarization():
    # yield values for each i
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        yield from grid(i)

result = list(polarization())
```

I've changed the `grid` function to return a list, and `polarization` function to yield values for each `i`.

As an aside, line `if data[i,0] == x` can be dangerous when you are dealing with floating point numbers. Instead, you may want to check if two numbers are numerically close, e.g. using `np.isclose`.

It is likely that you can speed things up rewriting `numpy` code or using `numba` in this case.

Comment: Thank you, this works! `if data[i,0] == x` works fine, because x also runs over the same column of data. Could you briefly explain what was wrong with my code and how your chances made it work? I found another post [lhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) which explains `yield` in detail, but I'd appreciate if you could tell me how changing `grid()` function into list comprehension made any difference?

Comment: `yield` is not super important here, I mainly used it for brevity. You original function `frac` did not have a return statement, so I added one. After that, we need `grid` to return a list of numbers. Now, polarization gets a list of numbers from each call to `grid`, and we need to somehow collect those together. One option is to keep appending lists together, another is to use yield.